# Saving from List<T> to txt

Tags: c#, save, generic-list

I want my program to read from two text files into one `List<T>`.
The `List<T>` is sorting and cleaning duplicates.

I want the `List<T>` to save (after sorting and cleaning) to a txt file.

But when I looked in the result txt file, I found this message:

> System.Collections.Generic.List`1[System.String]

Does anyone have an idea how I could fix this error?

Here is my code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.IO;

namespace Uniqpass
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {

            String pfad = "C:\\Dokumente und Einstellungen\\Bektas\\Desktop\\test\\";
            String pfad2 = "C:\\Dokumente und Einstellungen\\Bektas\\Desktop\\test\\";
            String speichern = "C:\\Dokumente und Einstellungen\\Bektas\\Desktop\\test\\ausgabe.txt";
            String datei = "text1.txt";
            String datei2 = "text2.txt";

            try
            {

                //Einlesen TxT 1
                List<String> pass1 = new List<String>();
                StreamReader sr1 = new StreamReader(pfad + datei);
                while (sr1.Peek() > -1)
                {

                    pass1.Add(sr1.ReadLine());
                }
                sr1.Close();
                //Einlesen TxT 2
                StreamReader sr2 = new StreamReader(pfad2 + datei2);
                while (sr2.Peek() > -1)
                {
                    pass1.Add(sr2.ReadLine());
                }
                sr2.Close();

                List<String> ausgabeListe = pass1.Distinct().ToList();
                ausgabeListe.Sort();

                ausgabeListe.ForEach(Console.WriteLine);

                StreamWriter file = new System.IO.StreamWriter(speichern);
                file.WriteLine(ausgabeListe);
                file.Close();


            }
            catch (Exception)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Error");
            }

            Console.ReadKey();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 74):

There's a handy little method [File.WriteAllLines](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.file.writealllines.aspx) -- no need to open a `StreamWriter` yourself:

In .net 4:

```
File.WriteAllLines(speichern, ausgabeListe);
```

In .net 3.5:

```
File.WriteAllLines(speichern, ausgabeListe.ToArray());
```

Likewise, you could replace your reading logic with [File.ReadAllLines](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/s2tte0y1.aspx), which returns an array of strings (use `ToList()` on that if you want a `List<string>`).

So, in fact, your complete code could be reduced to:

```
// Input
List<String> data = File.ReadAllLines(pfad + datei)
    .Concat(File.ReadAllLines(pfad2 + datei2))
    .Distinct().ToList();

// Processing
data.Sort(); 

// Output
data.ForEach(Console.WriteLine); 
File.WriteAllLines(speichern, data);
```

Comment: This answer is great as it reduces potentially several lines of code to a single line.

Comment: @Free2Rhyme2k: Yes, and less lines of code usually means less bugs.

Answer (score 10):

It's this line which writes the ToString representation of the List, resulting into the text line you got:

```
StreamWriter file = new System.IO.StreamWriter(speichern);
file.WriteLine(ausgabeListe);
file.Close();
```

Instead you want to write each line.

```
StreamWriter file = new System.IO.StreamWriter(speichern);
ausgabeListe.ForEach(file.WriteLine);
file.Close();
```

Answer (score 1):

Loop through the list, writing each line individually:

```
StreamWriter file = new System.IO.StreamWriter(speichern);
foreach(string line in ausgabeListe)
    file.WriteLine(line);
file.Close();
```

Answer (score 1):

Try the code below:

```
StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter("C:\\Users\\Alchemy\\Desktop\\c#\\InputFileFrmUser.csv");
list = new List<Product>() { new Product() { ProductId=1, Name="Nike 12N0",Brand="Nike",Price=12000,Quantity=50},
        new Product() { ProductId =2, Name = "Puma 560K", Brand = "Puma", Price = 120000, Quantity = 55 },
        new Product() { ProductId=3, Name="WoodLand V2",Brand="WoodLand",Price=21020,Quantity=25},
        new Product() { ProductId=4, Name="Adidas S52",Brand="Adidas",Price=20000,Quantity=35},
        new Product() { ProductId=5, Name="Rebook SPEED2O",Brand="Rebook",Price=1200,Quantity=15}};

foreach (var x in list) {
    string wr = x.ProductId + " " + x.Name + "" + x.Brand + " " + x.Quantity + " " + x.Price;
    writer.Flush();
    writer.WriteLine(wr);

}
Console.WriteLine("--------ProductList Updated SucessFully----------------");
```

Answer (score 0):

You are writing the list object into the file, so you see the type name.

Just as you are using `ForEach` to write the contents to the Console, you need to iterate over `ausgabeListe`, calling `WriteLine()` for each item in the list.

Answer (score 0):

```
StreamWriter file = new System.IO.StreamWriter(speichern);
foreach(string x in ausgabeListe)
    file.WriteLine(x);
file.Close();
```

Comment: Could you name the variables, such as "speichern" and "ausgabeListe" with something easier to understand?

Answer (score 0):

I am using the LINQ  like below to write each line to text file.

```
var myList=new List<string>
{
    "Hello",
    "World"
};
using (var file = new StreamWriter("myfile.txt"))
{
    myList.ForEach(v=>file.WriteLine(v));
}
```